# Call method from ruby file in haml?

Tags: ruby, haml

I am creating a simple html page displaying a table. The data to be filled in the table is retrieved in a ruby function in app.rb. I am trying to use haml to create the web page. I have an index.haml file in the views folder in which I have created the template for the web page

```
%body
 .table-div
   %table
     %tr
       %th //some ruby code to get the table header
     %tr
       %td //create td for each table row.
```

after this I need to call the ruby function get_table_header() and get_table_rows() in app.rb. what is the syntax for doing this? How do I include the reference to the ruby file in this haml?

Comment: add the functions you want to excute so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 6):

For a method to be available from a controller in the view, you need to specify it as a `helper` method in your controller. Something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :get_table_header, :get_table_row

  def get_table_header
    < code here >
  end

  def get_table_row
    < code here >
  end
end
```

Check out more: [Helper Methods](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method)

Then, there are two ways to execute Ruby code in HAML. First, use an '=' sign. This will execute ruby code and write (display) the returned result. I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
    %body
      .table-div
        %table
          %tr
            %th
              = get_table_header
          %tr
            %td 
              = get_table_row
```

This is the same as doing `<%= get_table_row %>` in ERB.

*Note: You don't need parentheses to execute Ruby methods. Secondly, these method names seem like HTML partials. You could abstract this code into another HAML file and call them in using the Rails Partial helper. You can learn more here [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)*

The second way to execute Ruby code in HAML is to use a hiphen. This is good for conditionals. For example:

```
-if <some condition is true>
  = get_table_header
-else
  = get_table_row
```

This is like doing `<% some code %>` in ERB. The returned result will not display on the page.  Also good for mapping iterating. Maybe if you have multiple table rows.

```
-dog_names = ["Teddy", "Skip", "Humphrey"]
-dogs_names.map do |name|
   %td= name
```

This would return 3  tags with a name.

```
<td>Teddy</td>
<td>Skip</td>
<td>Humphrey</td>
```

You can also include helper files as follow to your controller.
These Helpers will indeed hold the helper methods.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  include HelperOne
  include HelperTwo
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use `-r` option of the `haml` command

```
haml input.haml output.html -r ./ruby_file.rb
```

to call the ruby function and insert their values into output use the `=` operator

```
%body
 .table-div
   %table
     %tr
       %th= get_table_header 
     %tr
       %td= get_table_rows
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include functions from app.rb into your controller.